# How to debug the SQL Server error `the function "function name" is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause`

Tags: sql-server-2014

I get an error displayed as subject.

Here is my query.

```
select 
    X.*, 
    x.not_due + X.[1_30] + X.[31_60] + x.[61_90] + X.[91_120] + x.[121_150] + x.[151_over][ob], 
    case 
       when row_Number() over (partition by x.member_name order by x.partner_name, x.member_name, x.id) = 1 
          then dbo.LedgerS_RB_AsOf(X.member, 1, @asof2) over (partition by 1) 
    end as savings 
from 
    table X
```

Answer (score 1):

I already resolved it, I created a subquery instead of function.